# Convert bitmap to jpeg without using WriteableBitmap or similar in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, jpeg

I already know how to use the WriteableBitmap object (with the WriteableBitmapEx extensions) to convert a bitmap to a JPEG stream.  The problem is that WriteableBitmap objects must be created on the UI thread, mandating the user of RunAsync() or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to push the code to the UI thread, otherwise I get an RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD or UnauthorizedAccess exception.  Pushing the code to the UI thread makes the flow of the code harder to control and slows things down quite a bit by adding a thread switch.  Since my app is processing frames coming in from the phone's camera in real-time, that thread switch is a big performance hit.

Does anyone know how to convert a bitmap to a JPEG stream or array of bytes without using a WriteableBitmap object or any other object that has to be created/executed from the UI thread?

UPDATE: The bitmap source is a Stream object with the bitmap in its buffer.  The reason I am using WriteableBitmap is because I need to convert the bitmap to JPEG format and I am using Writeable bitmap to get that done.

Comment: What do you really have, a BitmapImage, a BitmapSource...?

Comment: I have a Stream object that has the bitmap in its buffer.

Comment: ehm... so why don't you read that stream to a byte array?

Comment: Because I need to convert it to a JPEG object and I am using WriteableBitmap to get that done. Adding that to my post now.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. You have a BMP in an stream and want to convert it to JPG, let me take a look, will be back in 5 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the managed version of libjpeg, [libjpeg.net](http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/)

Being compatible with Silverlight profile I assume it will work under Windows store apps, so with this you don't need to create any UI object.